# What should I download and how should I download so this code can work?

Tags: pandas, web, download

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd

import pandas_datareader.data as web**

df = web.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", start="2012-9-1", end="2017-8-31")
```

> RemoteDataError Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> ----> 1 df = web.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", start="2012-9-1", end="2017-8-31")
>
> 4 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py in _get_response(self, url, params, headers)
> 179             msg += "\nResponse >Text:\n{0}".format(last_response_text)
> 180
> --> 181         raise RemoteDataError(msg)
> 182
> 183     def _get_crumb(self, *args):
>
> RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=1346472000&period2=1504238399&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history
> Response Text:
> b'\n  \n  \n      \n      Yahoo\n      \n      \n      \n  html {\n      height: 100%;\n  }\n  body {\n      background: #fafafc url(https://s.yimg.com/nn/img/sad-panda-201402200631.png) 50% 50%;\n      background-size: cover;\n      height: 100%;\n      text-align: center;\n      font: 300 18px "helvetica neue", helvetica, verdana, tahoma, arial, sans-serif;\n  }\n  table {\n      height: 100%;\n      width: 100%;\n      table-layout: fixed;\n      border-collapse: collapse;\n      border-spacing: 0;\n      border: none;\n  }\n  h1 {\n      font-size: 42px;\n      font-weight: 400;\n      color: #400090;\n  }\n  p {\n      color: #1A1A1A;\n  }\n  #message-1 {\n      font-weight: bold;\n      margin: 0;\n  }\n  #message-2 {\n      display: inline-block;\n      *display: inline;\n      zoom: 1;\n      max-width: 17em;\n      _width: 17em;\n  }\n      \n  \n    document.write('&test=\'+encodeURIComponent(\'%\')+\'" width="0px" height="0px"/>');var beacon = new Image();beacon.src="//bcn.fp.yahoo.com/p?s=1197757129&t="+ne...

Comment: Probably something wrong with the library, maybe you don't have the recent version.

Comment: I use yfinance for such downloads anyway.

Comment: @BorutFlis Nothing wrong with the lib. 洪啓善 used Chinese date standard YYYY-M-D.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

aapl_df = yf.download('AAPL', 
                      start='2012-09-01', 
                      end='2017-08-31', 
                      progress=False,
)
aapl_df.head()
```

which gives:

```
         Open       High        Low      Close  Adj Close     Volume
Date                                                                        
2012-08-31  23.830357  23.878571  23.473213  23.758572  20.457228  338321200
2012-09-04  23.777143  24.112143  23.732143  24.106071  20.756439  367892000
2012-09-05  24.127501  24.155357  23.914286  23.936787  20.610680  336375200
2012-09-06  24.041786  24.224644  23.957144  24.152500  20.796421  391196400
2012-09-07  24.216070  24.374287  24.134644  24.301430  20.924654  329666400
...               ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...
2017-08-24  40.107498  40.185001  39.637501  39.817501  37.945786   79275600
2017-08-25  39.912498  40.139999  39.817501  39.965000  38.086349  101920400
2017-08-28  40.035000  40.500000  39.982498  40.367500  38.469933  103864000
2017-08-29  40.025002  40.779999  40.000000  40.727501  38.813004  118067600
2017-08-30  40.950001  40.972500  40.652500  40.837502  38.917839  109078400

[1257 rows x 6 columns]
```

Using your method also works if you write the dates right (you are using Chinese date standards ;-)):

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd

import pandas_datareader.data as web

df = web.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", start="2012-09-01", end="2017-08-31")
```